# Maximum value of increasing function over interval

Tags: calculus

> If $y=f(x)$ is defined in $a < x \leq b$ and is strictly increasing in $a<x<b$, then is $f(b)$ the maximum value of $f(x)$?

Since the function is increasing, as $x$ increases value of $y$ should also increase or as $x$ decreases value of $y$ should also decrease. So, for the function $f(x)$ defined in $a < x \leq b$ shouldn't the maximum value of $f(x)$ in that range be $f(b)$ ?
But, I read in a book that $f(b)$ is not always the maximim value. Can someone please explain with a suitable example ?
Thank you !

Comment: If is defined on $(a,b)$ then $f(b)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: I thought $f$ isn’t defined in $b$

Comment: If you meant $a \leq x \leq b$, then yes, and isn't this true just by definition?

Comment: Do you mean $f$ defined on $a\le x\le b$ and strictly increasing on $a<x<b?$

Comment: Your description in the body wasn't displayed because you used < outside of math mode (dollar signs).

Comment: @mfl might be interpreting the problem correctly.

Comment: OP, can I make the following suggestion? Your question should be "if $f$ is defined on $a < x \leq b$ and is strictly increasing over $a < x < b$, must $f(b)$ be the maximum value of $f$?

Comment: I voted to close the question because it is unclear what the OP is asking.

Comment: OK, with this last edit I think you have a well-defined and clear question.  Good.

Comment: Define $f(x) = x$ for $x \in (a,b)$ and $f(b) = f(a)$. Then there is no maximum value.

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$ then $f$ strictly increasing on $(a,b)$ is not enough imply that $f(b) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.  For example, define $f$ on $[0,1]$ by
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x  &\text{ if } x \in [0,1)
\\
0 &\text{ if } x = 1
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}

If $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$ and strictly increasing on $[a,b]$, then we can say that $f(b) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: I think your last sentence is false. Take a line of slope 1 til the end, but then drop the $y$-coordinate at $x=b$ by a ton. (Unless you are now assuming $f$ increases across the entire *closed* interval.)

Comment: Sorry, I think I was operating under the assumption that $f$ is stricly increasing on $[a,b]$.

Comment: "If $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$ then $f(b) > f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$" is not necessarily true. $f(x)=x, 0\le x<1; f(1)=0$ is strictly increasing on $(0,1)$ but $f(1/2)>f(1).$

Comment: @Randall I think I fixed it.

Comment: @mattstokes  Yeah, I agree now, only I'd be inclined to delete my comments in light of the edits, but one of the edits references the comments.

Comment: @Randall Sorry, for all the sloppiness.  Should be even better now.

Comment: Yep, I upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

No, because $f$ need not be defined at $x=b$. As an example, take the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{b-x}$, for $x \in (a,b)$. This is increasing, but is not defined at $b$, so there cannot be a maximum at $b$.

Comment: This is a correct answer and good for the OP to see, but the question is still unsatisfactory since $f(b)$ doesn't even make sense to begin with.

Comment: I agree. Maybe a trick question?

Comment: To remedy this and make everyone (ok, me) happy, OP should take your example and make a piecewise function with a $y$-coordinate at $b$ still showing the claim is false.